# How to add context menu option to registered extension?

Tags: windows, winapi, registry, explorer

I add a custom menu option to context menu for my own extension by writing to the Registry this way:

```
Key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.mown
Value = MyOWN

Key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\MyOWN
Value = My Own Extension

Key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\MyOWN\DefaultIcon
Value = C:\Project1.exe

Key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\MyOWN\shell\open\command
Value = C:\Project1.exe "%1"
```

This works fine. 
Now I add custom menu option:

```
Key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\MyOWN\shell\hello
Value = &Hello

Key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\MyOWN\shell\hello\command
Value = C:\Project1.exe "%1"
```

and it works too.
But when I want to add my custom option (hello) to an extension that's not mine then it doesn't work:

Key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.txt` says `TxtFile`, so I do:

```
Key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\TxtFile\shell\hello
Value = &Hello

Key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\TxtFile\shell\hello\command
Value = C:\Project1.exe "%1"
```

Comment: Stop trying to work this out in code. Edit the registry manually. Read the MSDN docs. Work out what needs to be done. Then code it. I trust your process runs elevated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tried editing it manually but it doesn't work either. I read MSDN docs but couldn't see anything about adding options to existing extensions.

Comment: I recommend that you remove the code, retag as winapi and convert this into a question about the registry. It's not a Delphi question at all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, I edited.

Comment: Does putting the change into HKCR make it work? On my system .txt isn't associated through HKCU.

Comment: What about HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt\UserChoice prodid value? Is it exist? Also you can try to use AssocQueryKey(ASSOCF_NONE, ASSOCKEY_CLASS, ...) to get HKEY of progid of extension. But it can be a key of HKLM and write access will require admin right. You can convert HKEY to string with NtQueryKey and create your context menu in HKCU instead of HKLM.

Comment: I would have expected this to work so I suspect that Windows 10 (or maybe 8) has changed how the context menu is built. Possibly HKCU is no longer considered for certain file classes? Or another key somewhere else overrides it. Just a guess. The file association system has grown ridiculously complicated over the years and Microsoft are incredibly bad at documenting this stuff so good luck finding out. If you go back to (e.g.) Window 7 I imagine you'll find it works again.